# Laravel 5 internal server error after moving to the server

Tags: .htaccess, server, laravel-5

My laravel 5 project is works well on localhost. After moving the project to the server it shows an internal server error.

**Error message**

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I checked the requirements. All requirements are correct.

```
PHP = 5.5
Mcrypt PHP Extension = Enabled
OpenSSL PHP Extension = Enabled
Mbstring PHP Extension = Enabled
Tokenizer PHP Extension = Enabled
```

Both **.htaccess** files on the root and public folder are same,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tested by removing the both `.htaccess` files but it still shows the Internal server error.

How Can I fix this issue ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check the server logs and see what the error actually is...

Comment: check file permission for `index.php`, I mean set it to 755 or 777

Comment: and... remember set `777` to `storage/` folder too

Answer (score 0):

check if mod_negotiation is enabled. I had the same issue just now

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while migrating the shared server . The solution that worked me is as below.

Let's say there is laravel folder called `test` which contains  folder structure of laravel.

I have use 2 different .htaccess file

1) one in the root folder of the (installed) laravel , i.e Along with `test` folder with content as below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/public/$1 [L]
```

2) One in the public folder i.e inside test/public with content as below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It worked for me.